# Get x and y coordinates of an image according to the superview's centre position in ios

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to find x and y coordinates of an image which can be scaled and moved relative to the view's centre position.x and y coordinates of for one position should be the same in any device.thats why I want to find image position coordinates because image resolution is not changing regardless of the device. I have attached the source code what I have tried to do so far. can anyone give me a suggestion to do this?
[link to the GitHub project](https://github.com/Navoda-BrightSparks/ImageCoordinateTest)

I was able to get exactly image coordinates by touching the image this is how I tried this but I want to get that coordinates using a pin by button click event

```
    @objc func tapAction(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)     
    {
    let touchPoint: CGPoint = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: 
    self.imageView)
    let Z1 = imageView.image!.size.height

    let Z2 = imageView.image!.size.width

    let Z3 = imageView.bounds.minY

    let Z4 = imageView.bounds.minX

    let Z5 = imageView.bounds.height

    let Z6 = imageView.bounds.width

    let pos1 = (touchPoint.x - Z4) * Z2 / Z6

    let pos2 = (touchPoint.y - Z3) * Z1 / Z5

    let ZZ1 = "\(pos1)"

    let ZZ2 = "\(pos2)"
    tochpointvalues.text = "Touched point x:\(ZZ1), y:\(ZZ2)"
    print("Touched point (\(ZZ1), \(ZZ2)")
}
```

Comment: So, you want the image coordinates with respect to the view. right?

Comment: yes, .i want to get image coordinates respect to the view without tapping a location in the image.

Answer (score 0):

To get the (x, y) coordinate of a child view in relative to its superview, you can use `convert(_ :, to:)` method. Example:

`let childCoordinate = parentView.convert(childView.frame.origin, to: parentView)`